# Google App Engine - Go vs. Python recommendations?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, go

I'm looking into writing my first application of [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/). C# is my 'native' language, and so writing the app in Java would of course be most logical. BUT, I'm a geek and would like to take to opportunity to learn something new.

Therefore its a toss-up between Python and [Go](http://golang.org/).

- Do you have a strong preference based on experience (ideally in the context of writing on App Engine).
- If you've come from C# (or another similar language), how was the transition?

Comment: If you're coming from C#, then prepare to have your mind blown. :-) Neither language is significantly similar to C#

Comment: Interesting.  I just tested out a fibonacci program implemented in Go and Python.  Go consistently computes F37 in 0.6s while Python does it in 20s.  At least for this straight computation, Go is *significantly* more efficient.  Perhaps Go's compilation to native code gives it this edge?

Comment: @hyperslug I'm surprised that someone would find it interesting that Go programs are far faster than Python programs, since this is a very well known fact and is a direct consequence of their design. Go is similar to C and C++ -- statically typed and directly compiled to a native executable. There's not much that's slower than Python other than Ruby.

Comment: Incidentally, a person is born every day who isn’t aware of the “well-known fact” that Go performs better than Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The recently-released Go runtime for App Engine is labelled experimental for a reason: Both Go and Go-on-appengine are new and in a state of change.

If you want to experiment with Go and running Go apps in the cloud, go for it. If you want to write a production app on App Engine, use Python or Java.

Comment: As of March 28 2012, GO is now out of beta: http://blog.golang.org/2012/03/go-version-1-is-released.html

Comment: *Go* is out of beta, but as of Aug 24, 2012, *Go support in GAE* is still marked "Experimental".

Answer (score 5):

This question is about as subjective as they come, but I'll bite anyway.

Python is easier to learn, has a much larger development community, is mature, and has a lot of third-party libraries available for you to integrate into your application. It's a winner for sure.

That said, Go is an extremely well-designed language. Far, far more so than Python. Go was specifically designed to allow you to catch most mistakes at compile time, while Python is almost legendary for its ability to mask your mistakes. Go code tends to be easier to maintain. Go is also dramatically more efficient than Python -- several times faster or even several orders of magnitude faster, depending on what you're doing.

Both languages are very powerful and very fast to write code in -- you can accomplish a lot in a short amount of space. But Go is unfinished and still in a state of flux, with core APIs still changing. It has a comparatively small developer base, and very few "real world" usage examples. Nonetheless, even this early in its development, it's already shown to be a compelling alternative with a clear use case.

Comment: *"Go code tends to be easier to maintain."* - Do you have evidence for this?!

Comment: "Go is an extremely well-designed language. Far, far more so than Python" - despite your POV disclaimer, this sounds factual when in actual fact it's highly contentious. I think both are well designed languages - static vs dynamic is a completely different argument.

Comment: @ThomasH: The only evidence of something being "easy" is necessarily going to be personal experience, and not scientific at all. But the claim is based on the personal experiences of about a dozen people I talked to when deciding whether or not to learn Go. The claim is rooted in the fact that Go allows for the same flexibility as you see in Python while at the same time leveraging its type system to reduce ambiguity and errors. Though, again, totally subjective.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: "well-designed" is clearly a matter of your perspective and opinion, but the claim is rooted in the fact that Go was designed by highly experienced language designers (Ken Thompson, Rob Pike) who have been through this rodeo several times. Guido is no slouch, but it's hard to compete with the people that the rest of us only read about in college text books. Python has the distinct advantage of having gone through more iterations, though, which shouldn't be underestimated.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: There was a good presentation given by Rob Pike about the language design of Go. There's a PDF of the slides [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee380/Abstracts/100428-pike-stanford.pdf). Even after just reading the slides, you get an idea of the forethought that went into designing the language.

Comment: @tylerl Re "easy to maintain": I understand. I thought you maybe talked to people that have both like 10KLOC Python code and 10KLOC Go code to maintain, so they have a direct comparison. - Re "Ken Thompson, Rob Pike": I wouldn't connect age and experience automatically with good designs. Although I also don't want to indicate otherwise in this case :-).

Comment: "Go is an extremely well-designed language. Far, far more so than Python." -- that is utter nonsense, and your arguments from authority about Thompson and Pike are even worse. Here's a clue: *you* are not an experienced language designer, so you're not in a good position to judge.

Comment: If want to see really well-designed languages, look at Haskell and Scala.

Comment: "Go is also dramatically more efficient than Python" -- Of course it is -- Go was designed to be efficient, and Python was designed with Moore's Law in mind. Python suffers from sloth like any dynamically typed language. But Go is not nearly as flexible as Python -- type inference and interfaces aren't enough ... and heavy use of interfaces will cost at runtime. Go doesn't have generics, so you have to either give up type safety and speed or duplicate a lot of code. Scala shows the power of a good type system that Go can't touch.

Comment: @Jim Balter """your arguments from authority about Thompson and Pike are even worse. Here's a clue: you are not an experienced language designer, so you're not in a good position to judge.""" -- Way to contradict yourself! """ Scala. – Jim Balter""" OK, you don't know anything about nicely designed languages either, we get it.

Comment: Regarding performance, what about runtime Go versus interpreted python?

Answer (score 5):

I did a Python app for GAE recently and coming from C# I had no problems/was able to pick it up in a few days tinkering with the docs and playing with the SDK (I had some previous experience with python).
Python is pretty intuitive, it's imperative and OO, might require a slight change in thinking from C# but nothing revolutionary - using the interactive interpreter will allow you to pick it up in a day IMO. 
Learning how to use the datastore and figuring out other GAE specific API's (blobstore, image, mail) will probably be more work (it's specifics like transactions/groups, consistency modes ...) but you can figure that stuff out as you go/when you need it in your app.

One thing to note - recently announced pricing scheme makes Python a bad choice on GAE ATM because it cannot handle requests currently and this leads to one "instance" per request. This is also true for Go ATM (as far as I know). JVM OTOH can handle ~20 simultaneous requests per instance if I remember the mailing list conversations correctly. And you will be paying per instance/hour. This makes JVM the most practical choice if you plan on publishing your application in the near future.

Also using JVM you could use Scala (a new/cool language) and a framework like Lift which should theoretically allow you to port your code/avoid lock-in (disclaimer : I say *theoretically* because I'm only starting out with Scala and have no practical experience with Lift).

So I would recommend to look around the mailing list and see what other people are saying about the recent changes.

Comment: Python 2.7 supports threaded concurrency:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would **prefer Python because is much, much more mature than `Go`**.

In the past, I learnt, the hard way, what are the risks of choosing a not-so-mature technology.

Warning, I am biased to recommend `Python` because I like it but you should also be careful because I heard many complains about how much support does Google put on Python-App-Engine. People are asking for years to upgrade Python support and nobody hears them.

These being said, probably Java would be a smarter choice, especially because you are used to `C#`.

Answer (score 3):

Go is still experimental on the GAE - so maybe not the best platform to learn a new language. Python is definitely a good choice.

Considering a new language do not forget that by choosing Java you get the JVM which allows not only Java code but also oder languages like: Scala, Grails, Clojure, JRuby any many others.

Comment: By choosing the JVM you get all those languages; you don't have to write in Java at all.

Answer (score 1):

Python is since long supported on GAE - lots of tested information, infrastructure, etc. Go is new to GAE.

I would decide more on the language level. Coming from C#, choosing Python you go a bit more "high-level", whereas choosing Go goes more into the "low-level" direction. More low-level control, but also more concern about that. Choose Python if your interest is on application development, and Go if it's more about systems development. One important aspect for me would be that Go has actor-style concurrency built in, though I don't know how well supported this on GAE will be.

Comment: Don't confuse "low-level" with "efficient". Go is perhaps more suitable for writing low-level applications, but the language itself is certainly as "high-level" as python. You don't have to manage memory or synchronization or worry about the machine-level intricacies of how your program works.

Comment: Go is not as high-level as Python, if for no other reason than that Go has pointers, and there are other reasons.